# Xamarin Forms: accessing data in CollectionView

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I'm unable to undestand how to access data in CollectionView DataTemplate generated child controls. My XAML code is below. I want to get RadioButton values of all items. Please give me some ideas.

```
<CollectionView x:Name="ItemsListView"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Questions}"
    SelectionMode="None">
    
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackLayout Padding="10" >
                <Label Text="{Binding Category}" 
                LineBreakMode="NoWrap"
                Style="{DynamicResource ListItemTextStyle}"
                FontSize="16" />
                
                <Label Text="{Binding Text}" 
                LineBreakMode="WordWrap" 
                Style="{DynamicResource ListItemTextStyle}" 
                FontSize="16" />
                
                <Grid HorizontalOptions="Fill" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="0" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <RadioButton Content="Yes" Grid.Column="1" Style="{DynamicResource ListItemTextStyle}"/>
                    <RadioButton Content="No" Grid.Column="2" Style="{DynamicResource ListItemTextStyle}"/>
                    <RadioButton Content="N/A" Grid.Column="3" Style="{DynamicResource ListItemTextStyle}"/>
                </Grid>

                <Editor x:Name="comment" Text="" AutoSize="TextChanges" Style="{DynamicResource ListItemTextStyle}" />

            </StackLayout>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

Comment: you **bind** them to properties in your VM.  This is exhaustively covered in the docs and many online examples

Comment: `<RadioButton Content="Yes" IsChecked={Binding YesChecked} …`. `public bool YesChecked { get … set …`. There is also a [CheckedChanged event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/radiobutton#respond-to-an-event-firing).

Comment: Thanks both. I've binded the properties and it worked great. solved.

Comment: That's great! Consider adding "Your Answer" below, showing all the changes you made, to handle one button, and where those changes go in the code. This might help others in the future. (Its fine that your answer is based on suggestions in these comments; people always appreciate seeing a complete code example.)

Answer (score 0):

As Jason and Steve suggested,the best practice is using [MVVM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/enterprise-application-patterns/mvvm).
Below is code snippet for your reference:

In your XAML:

```
 <RadioButton Content="Yes" Grid.Column="1" IsChecked="{Binding YesChecked}" Style="{DynamicResource ListItemTextStyle}"/>
 <RadioButton Content="No" Grid.Column="2"  IsChecked="{Binding NoChecked}" Style="{DynamicResource ListItemTextStyle}"/>
 <RadioButton Content="N/A" Grid.Column="3" IsChecked="{Binding N_AChecked}" Style="{DynamicResource ListItemTextStyle}"/>
```

Then in your view model,use like below:

```
    public bool yesChecked;
    public bool YesChecked
    {
        get { return yesChecked; }
        set
        {
            yesChecked = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("YesChecked"));
        }
    }
```